# c# Platform game optimization issue + player studdering

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry if I made stupid mistakes,
I hope you can help me out! 
So my game looks kinda laggy when i Run it, my player studders and if I add gifs instead of image's then everything is very slow :/
I used pictureboxes as Image's

Here is my code (I just used one class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectBlok1Remake
{
    public partial class myGame : Form
    {
        bool jump = false;
        bool right = false;
        bool left = false;

        int score = 0;
        int jumpspeed = 10;
        int force = 8;

        System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("muziek.wav");

        public myGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sp.Play(); // play music :)

        }



        private void myGame_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                right = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Close(); //exist the game
            }

            if (jump != true)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    jump = true;
                }
            }

        }

        private void myGame_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                right = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                left = false;
            }
            if (jump)
            {
                jump = false;
            }


        }

        private void AddPoints(int valueCoin)
        {
            score = valueCoin + score;

        }




        private void GameTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Top += jumpspeed;

            if (jump && force < 0)
            {
                jump = false;
            }

            if (left)
            {
                player.Left -= 5;
            }

            if (right)
            {
                player.Left += 5;
            }

            if (jump)
            {
                jumpspeed = -12;
                force -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                jumpspeed = 12;
            }

            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "platform")
                {
                             if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
                    {
                        force = 8;
                        player.Top = x.Top - player.Height;
                    }
                }

                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "coin")
                {
                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
                    {
                        this.Controls.Remove(x); //will remove current touched coin :)
                        AddPoints(5); // each coin taken, will increase the score with 5 points!

                    }
                }
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "bigCoin")
                {
                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
                    {
                        this.Controls.Remove(x); //will remove current touched coin :)
                        AddPoints(15); ; // each coin taken, will increase the score with 15 points!

                    }
                }
                this.scoreLabel.Text = "score: " + score;


            }
            if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(door.Bounds))
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                sp.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! YOU WON THE GAME! + \n With a total score of: " + score + "\n Exit the game with escape (2x)");
            }

            if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds))
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                sp.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("YOU DIED, GAME OVER! :c");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is an Image of how the game looks like, All the Image's you see are uploaded from a file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QiIc.png

Comment: Does it actually works? You are not doing anything when the player hits his left or right or up side. Only his bottom. And he studders because you first set his position, `player.Top += jumpspeed;,` and **then** check for intersection and if he does, `player.Top = x.Top - player.Height;`. That produces the studder.

Comment: Yes it works, and if there is no "player.Top = x.Top - player.Height" he just falls through the panels and dies.
"player.Top += jumpspeed" indeed does the studdering!:D thank you! but if i delete that, there is no gravity and he can't jump or fall
thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...but if i delete that, there is no gravity and he can't jump...*. I didn't say to delete it. I just pointed the problem of changing the position of the player prior the intersect checking. The way you do it is to chech **if** the new position is ok **then** change it:

CODE:

```
private void GameTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Don't change the position of the player but a copy one, playerClone!
    Rectangle playerClone = player.Bounds; 

    playerClone.Y += jumpspeed;

    if (jump && force < 0)
    {
        jump = false;
    }

    if (left)
    {
        playerClone.X -= 5;
    }

    if (right)
    {
        playerClone.X += 5;
    }

    if (jump)
    {
        jumpspeed = -12;
        force -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        jumpspeed = 12;
    }

    foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "platform")
        {
            if (playerClone.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
            {
                force = 8;
                playerClone.Y = x.Top - playerClone.Height;
            }
        }

        if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "coin")
        {
            if (playerClone.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(x); //will remove current touched coin :)
                AddPoints(5); // each coin taken, will increase the score with 5 points!

            }
        }
        if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "bigCoin")
        {
            if (playerClone.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds) && !jump)
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(x); //will remove current touched coin :)
                AddPoints(15); ; // each coin taken, will increase the score with 15 points!

            }
        }
        this.scoreLabel.Text = "score: " + score;


    }
    if (playerClone.IntersectsWith(door.Bounds))
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        sp.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! YOU WON THE GAME! + \n With a total score of: " + score + "\n Exit the game with escape (2x)");

        return;
    }

    if (playerClone.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds))
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        sp.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("YOU DIED, GAME OVER! :c");

        return;
    }

    //And now set the player position
    player.Bounds = playerClone;

}
```